# How to add php if condition in this tag?

Tags: php

How to add php if condition in this tag ?

...................................................................................................................................................................

My old code is

```
<?PHP
.
.
.
.
.
      $str.="<div cslass='level'>BEST</div>";
.
.
.
.
?>
```

i want to apply this, but not work

```
<?PHP
.
.
.
.
.
      $str.="
                 <div cslass='level'>
                     if($row[point] > 3){ echo 'BEST'; }
                 </div>
             ";
.
.
.
.
?>
```

Comment: Please clean up your code, and make sure your question is clear.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SPAM.

Comment: How do you know it's about spam?

Answer (score 0):

Just string concatenation

```
$str .= '<div class="level">'.($row['point'] > 3 ? 'BEST' : '').'</div>';
```

Comment: How to add image tag too

i try this but not work

`$str .= '<div class="level">'.($row['point'] > 3 ? 'BEST' : '').'</div> <img id = "bnn" src="$row[img];">'';`

Comment: @การการการนานานายานายา Use double quotes to parse variables in string, `."</div> <img id='bnn' src='{$row['point']}'/>";`

Answer (score -2):

The easy solution would be:

```
 $str.="
             <div cslass='level'>";
                 if($row[point] > 3){ $str .=  'BEST'; }
             $str .= "</div>
         ";
```

Llet me know if you want a different approach.